# Google Cloud SDK installer fails on Windows 7 (gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError))

Tags: windows, installation, google-cloud-sdk

My OS is win7. I want to install the clould SDK.
But it "Failed to install". The ERROR message is:

```
Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback
To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
ERROR: Cannot use bundled Python installation to update Cloud SDK in
non-interactive mode. Please run again in interactive mode.
If you really want to run in non-interactive mode, please run the
following command before re-running this one:
 FOR /F "delims=" %i in ( '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd"" components copy-bundled-python'
 ) DO (
SET CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=%i
)
(Substitute `%%i` for `%i` if in a .bat script.)
Failed to install.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you attempting to install? Is this still occurring for you?

Comment: I got exact the same issue i will let know how to fix when i found out

Comment: I've got the same issue if I install for all users. But it works fine for a single user installation.

Answer (score 6):

I Fixed it by re-installing google cloud sdk. (if you can't uninstall just rename folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK` to something else and try installer)

And by setting the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable to `C:\Python27\python.exe` (installation folder of python v2.7)

[image]

Now installing the app-engine components worked again.

### option 2

Check your config: `gcloud config list` if you see: `disable_prompts = True`. this is probably why google says the inter-active mode is disabled. if you remove this value it might remove this error.

Comment: I'm (along with OP) trying to install it for the first time. Also I don't have Python installed and suppose "Bundled Python" configuration option have to work

Answer (score 3):

I also had error on Windows 8

> ERROR: gcloud failed to load: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...

1. I checked my installation path. And it contained non-ascii symbol. So I restarted installer and changed installation path to `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK`

Afterwards I've got error

> To use the Google Cloud SDK, you must have Python installed and on your PATH.
>   As an alternative, you may also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable
>   to the location of your Python executable.
>   Failed to install.

despite the checked option "Bundled Python" as [manual proposes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).

2. I downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/ and installed latest Python 2.7.14 (Google SDK doesn't work with Python 3)
3. The default path to executable was `C:\Python27\python.exe`, so added it as CLOUDSDK_PYTHON system variable in my Control panel and started again.

Finally it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

My local account name contains non-ASCII characters.

I workarounded this issue by creation of new local account with name of ASCII characters only.