# What is a solution for this trouble, that happens when I try to install Google Cloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The problem I have when I try to install the Google Cloud SDK from the Google Page or from the Eclipse Marketplace, is this one:

```
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro de Jesús\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to install.
```

I'm looking forward to installing the Google Cloud SDK, because I'm using Eclipse JEE Oxygen, so I need the SDK to be installed. I'm using Windows 10, Intel Core i7 and I am also wondering why the installation process works on another computers with the same hardware as mine.

Comment: Potentially of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895848/google-cloud-sdk-installer-fails-on-windows-7-gcloud-crashed-unicodedecodeerro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615607/google-cloud-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe1-during-installation)

Answer (score -1):

```
'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfa'
```

Byte 0xfa is equal to character **ú** (this can be seen **[here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/programming_resources/PROGRAMMING_ascii_table.shtml)** in the 'Extended ASCII Characters' table), which can be seen in the filepath that you provided:

File *"C:\Users\Pedro de Jes**ú**s..."*

Rename this filepath using non-ascii characters only before re-trying the installation.